# Combining 2 MySQL queries with IN clause does not work

Tags: mysql

I have a 2-step query that I am trying to combine into one.

This returns the ids:

```
select  id
from    (select * from comments
        where deleted_at is NULL AND is_removed=0 and commentable_type LIKE "App%Comment"
         order by commentable_id, id) products_sorted,
        (select @pv := '26') initialisation
where   find_in_set(commentable_id, @pv)
and     length(@pv := concat(@pv, ',', id))
;
```

-- Then I take the results for parent id=26 (from prior query) and put them in an IN clause.

```
SELECT * FROM reactions 
WHERE deleted_at is NULL AND is_removed=0 AND reactable_type LIKE "App%Comment"
AND
reactable_id IN
(
30,
31,
33,
34,
50,
51,
52,
53,
36,
37,
38,
39,
40,
41,
42,
43,
44,
45,
5819,
6083,
5921,
6390,
54,
56,
57,
58,
59,
60,
61,
62,
5779
)
;
```

However when I combine the above 2 into one query, this does NOT work and returns a much shorter set of results:

```
----------------------
SELECT * FROM reactions r
WHERE r.deleted_at is NULL AND r.is_removed=0 AND r.reactable_type LIKE "App%Comment"
AND
r.reactable_id IN
(
select  id
from    (select * from comments
        where deleted_at is NULL AND is_removed=0 and commentable_type LIKE "App%Comment"
         order by commentable_id, id) products_sorted,
        (select @pv := '26') initialisation
where   find_in_set(commentable_id, @pv)
and     length(@pv := concat(@pv, ',', id))
)
;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Using variables for chain assignement without non-duplicated ORDER BY is a lottery. Subexpressions evaluation order in complex WHERE is not documented - one more lottery. If first query gives correct result - ir is random, not a rule.

Comment: The individual queries do give the correct results, and I'm looking for a way to combine them. I'm sure there's a solution here...

Answer (score 0):

You have basically two problems here,

1. Your sub-query is returning row-based results and you need comma-separated results.
   You could fix this issue by using the GROUP_CONCAT(value SEPARATOR ',') like this:

   ...r.reactable_id IN
   (
   select  GROUP_CONCAT(id SEPARATOR ',')
   from    (select * from comments...

But you won't see any result due to the next problem...

2. Different types (reactable_id is an INT value and the GROUP_CONCAT result is a STRING value. So your final solution is to rewrite your query using JOINS instead of sub-queries.

   You can see this post to guide your steps:
   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6135376/mysql-select-where-field-in-subquery-extremely-slow-why

Comment: Thank you @jesus-uzcanga what you say makes sense. I'm just not sure how a JOIN can be done here. Would you mind editing your answer to show how?